# Can't restore using BackInTime: nothing happens

Tags: ubuntu, backup, restore, kubuntu

It all should be simple, but I probably miss some detail:

1. Made two backups (successfully)
2. Choose one backup (successfully)
3. Select it and press 'restore' - nothing happens, the files are not restored

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the software is updated anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-launched the BackInTime GUI from the command line (previously was launched via KDE launcher) and seen a message:

> QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths:
>   inotify_add_watch failed: No such file
>   or directory QFileSystemWatcher:
>   failed to add paths:
>   /home/breakphreak/.config/ibus/bus

When created the directory that wasn't there (/home/breakphreak/.config/ibus/bus), the restore button triggered an action but with a little success: got the following message:

> INFO: Restore: /mnt/raid/pix/pic.jpg
>   rsync: mkstemp
>   "/mnt/raid/pix/.pic.jpg.2Zv0IT"
>   failed: Permission denied (13) rsync
>   error: some files/attrs were not
>   transferred (see previous errors)
>   (code 23) at main.c(1060)
>   [sender=3.0.7] WARNING: Command "rsync
>   -rtDH --links --no-p --no-g --no-o -R --backup --suffix=.backup.20110525 "/mnt/backup/backintime/beatkeeper/breakphreak/1/20110524-113821-277/backup/./mnt/raid/pix/pic.jpg"
>   /" returns 5888 INFO: Restore
>   permissions

Opened a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can always restore manually from the last snapshot. Go inspect the backup with a file browser: you will see that all your files are there.

Comment: that's true, but what is the function of the "restore" button in that case? how about other snapshots then?

Comment: Ok, other snapshots work fine and the files are restored using the drag-n-drop interface. If noone will answer otherwise - I'd assume that the "restore" button is kinda bug and will mark your answer as the only real one (at least for my case).

Comment: Meanwhile, have another problem with `BackInTime`, just for a case that someone from the readers/repliers would like to have a look: http://superuser.com/questions/287854/backintipe-kompare-cannot-parse-diff-output-when-comparing-snapshots - if it is against the policy - kindly tell and I will remove it.

Comment: I think you should definitely file a bug.

Comment: Just submitted the bug (along with two others) to the team. We will see if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I opened the Backintime gui from the command line using sudo and it works. I needed to adjust the user in the profile options (from root to my user).