# BackInTime/Kompare: cannot parse diff output when comparing snapshots

Tags: ubuntu, backup, home-server, kubuntu

Actually, the subject is pretty self-explanatory: trying to compare (diff) two snapshots using BackInTime utility, selecting two different snapshots, the `kompare` window is displayed as empty along with the dialog box that says that the diff output cannot be parsed.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitted a bug report (though maybe the problem is that some of the files have non-English names).